# AutoMapper - How to Map to three level deep

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, automapper

I'm trying to user AutoMapper to flatten a Entity with relation to another Entity which has relation to third Entity to view model

How to map these three entities into one?

Source:

```
public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }       
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public virtual City City { get; set; }  
}

public class City
{
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
public class Country
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

Destination:

```
Public Class AddressViewModel
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }       
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ways (at least). If you name your viewmodel fields differently it can happen by convention:

```
Public Class AddressViewModel
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }       
    public int CityCityId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("City Name")]
    public string CityCityName { get; set; }
    public int CityCountryCountryId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Country Name")]
    public string CityCountryCountryName { get; set}
}
```

If that's too ugly, you can do it in CreateMap:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Address, AddressViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CityId, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.City.CityId))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CityName, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.City.CityName))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CountryId, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.City.Country.CountryId))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CountryName, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.City.Country.CountryName));
```

http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Flattening&referringTitle=Home

Comment: Have you tried any of them? I have tried both solutions, the first one is working up to level two only CityCityName will work, but CityCountryCountryName will not-- as well as the second it is not working for me.

Comment: Yes, I have some that go 4 levels deep. What does your context code look like? Are you Including() all levels?

Comment: I'll try it now with include and i will be back

Comment: Is there anyway to solve this while getting the result as a concatenated string of all names (city, state, country) aside from having all the properties using ProjectTo?
At least when I use ProjectTo, those properties don't get loaded and then the "FullAddress" string becomes wrong.

Comment: For those situatons, I prefer to just create a property in the destination view model that does the concatenation. You could also do string operations in the MapFrom as long as they are SQL compatible (i.e. not c# functions). Yet another way is a SQL computed column.

Answer (score 0):

Example to use Include() to query data in deeper levels:

```
    public AddressViewModel GetAddressById(int id)
    {
        var result = applicationDbContext.Address
            .Include(o=>o.City)
            .Include(o=>o.City.Country)
            .FirstOrDefault(x=>x.AddressId == id);
        return mapper.Map<AddressViewModel>(result);
    }
```